# Vue como cambiar los estilos al tomar un valor de un select

Tags: vue.js, select

Tengo un select en un componente, y al seleccionar un valor quiero que que cambien los estilos de un span para resultarlos en una tabla.
cómo se podría hacer de una manera eficiente y efectiva

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como se podria hacer es una pregunta que puede tener montones de respuestas.. mejor muestra lo que tienes, como lo intentaste y de ahi correjimos tu logica...

Answer (score 0):

Quizás buscas algo así:

```html
<template>
  <div :class="['common-styles', selectedClass]">
    <select name="selectClass" @change="onChange($event)">
      <option
        v-for="(option, id) in options"
        :key="id"
        :value="option.className"
        :selected="option.selected"
      >
        {{ option.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      selectedClass: "",
      options: [
        { name: "Black", className: "", selected: true },
        { name: "Red", className: "redClass" },
        { name: "Blue", className: "blueClass" },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      this.selectedClass = event.target.value;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```css
<style>
#app {
  text-align: center;
}

.common-styles {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.redClass {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.blueClass {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>
```